# How to create virtual hosts with https in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, https

i need to know how to serve multiple projects using virtual hosts but using https.

I can easily do this in http using only express and vhost. But i can't get to work with https. I have key and certificate for all my projects.

I basically need to have https://subdomain.example.com and https://example.com running both in the port 443.

What i tried and didn't work:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = express();

// FOODIFY ============================================================================================================
var credenciaisCliente = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/foodify/certificados/cliente/private.key", "utf8"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/foodify/certificados/cliente/certificate.crt", "utf8"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/foodify/certificados/cliente/ca_bundle.crt", "utf8")
};

var credenciaisAdministracao = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/foodify/certificados/administracao/private.key", "utf8"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/foodify/certificados/administracao/certificate.crt", "utf8"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/foodify/certificados/administracao/ca_bundle.crt", "utf8")
};

var foodifyAdministracao = express();
foodifyAdministracao.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/foodify/cliente/administracao"));
foodifyAdministracao.get("*", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/foodify/cliente/administracao/index.html");
});
var httpsFoodifyAdministracao = https.createServer(credenciaisAdministracao, foodifyAdministracao);

var foodifyCliente = express();
foodifyCliente.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/foodify/cliente/cliente"));
foodifyCliente.get("*", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/foodify/cliente/cliente/index.html");
});
var httpsFoodifyCliente = https.createServer(credenciaisCliente, foodifyCliente);

var foodifyAdministracaoHost = vhost("administracao.foodify.com.br", foodifyAdministracao);
var foodifyHost = vhost("*.foodify.com.br", foodifyCliente);

server.use(httpsFoodifyAdministracao);
server.use(httpsFoodifyCliente);

server.listen(443, () => {
  console.log("Servido os projetos na porta 443 por https.");
});
```

I also tried some other libraries as dietjs but didn't work also.

Comment: Did you register your subdomain `subdomain.example.com` as valid domain name?

Comment: @ManfredSteiner Of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Redbird: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redbird

Redbird will listen on ports 80,443 and your other apps will listen on their own unique ports.  Redbird will route to those other ports from 80/443 based on domain name.

Comment: Worked with redbird and letsencrypt. Thank you so much, I love you

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a bit late, weeks ago I noticed that in NodeJS, the `tls` module offers a method called `server.addContext(hostname, creds)`, which takes in a hostname and its corresponding credentials. This means you can basically extend your HTTPS server with your subdomain and corresponding certificate. This has a benefit compared to other reverse proxy solutions (such as Redbird, node-http-proxy and Nginx) as it only requires listening on a single port (443) and requires only a single running node script.

I wrote a minimal package [vhttps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhttps) that wraps this and added virtual host features directly onto it (so you might not need the `vhost` package). You could probably check it out.